# Convert synchronous reader stream to asynchronous reader stream in Rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits, synchronous, derived-class

Is it possible to convert/wrap a `struct` that derives `std::io::Read` `trait` to `async_std::io::Read` `trait`?

Comment: Why dont you try to implement directly? You can do it, but the thing is that if you use the `std::io::Read` which is not asynchronous inside the other io::Read you will be losing performance. You would have to implement the reading again to take advantage of the async feature, otherwise is not worth it imo.